# Before opening android app through appium, getting notification regarding 'Block installation'. How to reslove?

Tags: selenium, automation, appium, appium-android

Before opening android app through appium, getting notification regarding 'Block installation'. How to resolve?

After display this notification, appium opens app but getting error: NullPointerException

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA7sE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem by enabling the unknown source settings, Go on Settings > Security > Device Administration check the box of 'Unknown Sources'

or

I am assuming by seeing you screenshot you are using antivirus app and it is blocking the `Appium settings` app, so you can try after disable the antivirus app.

Comment: Thanks Imran,as per your solution now main problem is resolved by unblocking Appium setting. But still fatching null pointer exception.

Comment: After open app, appium unable to perform any operation like click or enter data.

Comment: You welcome, could you please accept my answer, so that it might be helpful for others. Please create a new question with error log and your script, refer the link here.